# Laravel 5.3 polymorphic relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to get my head around my first polymorphic relationship in Laravel 5.3.

The relationship i am trying to achieve is that an 'Editorial' will have many 'Elements' each element will be its own Model and have an order.

So for example i will have an 'ElementText', 'ElementImage', 'ElementButton' models then an 'Editorial' will have various elements assigned to it.

This is why i think i need a polymorphic relationship. I don't want multiple relationships for each element type in the 'Editorials' model, i want to be able to just get all 'Elements' regardless of its type and get it in order.

I think the idea solution would be to have an 'editorial_element' pivot table with columns like

```
editorial_id - integer
order - integer
element_id - integer
element_type - string
```

similar to the `morphToMany`example in the laravel docs, but in that example you need to specify the model to morph.

So i also wondered if i should be using the morphTo() method in my Editorials model.

```
public function elements() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

But i think that means i would have to add `_type` and `_id` columns to my editorials table which would be backwards (allowing one element per editorial)

Any idea if i can set the relationship i require up or am i approaching it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think polymorphic relations are going to fit well here. I might approach it like so.

```
editorials
 - id
 - title
 - etc...

elements
 - editorial_id
 - elements_id
 - elements_type

elements_image
 - id
 - url

elements_text
 - id
 - text
```

Then your models can be.

```
class Editorial extends Model {

    // ...

    public function elements() {
        return $this->hasMany(\Element::class);
    }

    // ...

}

class Element extends Model {

    // ...

    public function editorial() {
        return $this->belongsTo(\Editorial::class);
    }

    public function image() {
        return $this->belongsTo(\ElementImage::class, 'elements_id');
    }

    public function text() {
        return $this->belongsTo(\ElementText::class, 'elements_id');
    }

    public function content() {
        $type = $this->elements_type;
        return $this->{$type}();
    }

    // ...

}

class ElementImage extends Model {

    // ...

    public function element() {
        return $this->hasOne(\Element::class, 'elements_id');
    }

    // ...

}

class ElementText extends Model {

    // ...

    public function element() {
        return $this->hasOne(\Element::class, 'elements_id');
    }

    // ...

}
```

Perhaps then you could make all elements implement an interface which forces a `render()` method on all elements and then you can do this in the view:

```
@foreach($editorial->elements as $element)
    {{ $element->content->render() }}
@endforeach
```

The render method can then be responsible for formatting and outputting the content.

This is all just theory, I'd be interested to see if you could get this to work because it's a problem I've tried to tackle before also. Please let me know of any corrections or if you think my idea is just dumb.

Comment: Understood, am i right in thinking that the 'elements' model will need to be updated manually and will no longer accept attach(), detach() methods using this approach?

Comment: `BelongsTo()` has `associate()` and `disassociate()` but I can't think of a situation where you would manipulate those relationships once you have created them. The only one I could see changing would be the `Editorial - hasMany - Element`, unfortunate there doesn't seem to be a `sync()` method for that but you can `saveMany()`.

Comment: I had a quick go at this approach before getting sent home from work early. I didn't use a view but did the following which worked 
    $editorial = \App\Editorials::with( 'elements' )->first();

    foreach ( $editorial->elements as &$elements ) {

  $elements->content;
 }. 
Wonder how it impacts performance..

Comment: You could eagar load all related models before looping and obviously you should cache but yes I imagine it wouldn't be the most performant thing in the world. You also inspired me to give it a go and I got a very rough version working. I've been trying to get it working as a generic solution that can be ported easily  for a while

Comment: Let me know how you get on if you would :) Can skype me vlowe85

Answer (score 0):

You should setup your relationship as below.

In your `Editorial` model you should have methods for each `Element*` model that it's morphed by. E.g.

```
public function textElements() {
    return $this->morphedByMany(ElementText::class, 'element');
}


public function buttonElements() {
    return $this->morphedByMany(ElementButton::class, 'element');
}
```

In your `Element*` models you should have the below method to get all the `Editorials` that it's morphed to.

```
public function editorials()
    return $this->morphToMany(Editorial::class, 'element');
}
```

**note:** There are some issues with using polymorphic relationships that is worth noting. The most important one is that yes you get some simplicity in your database structure but then at the same time you lose foreign key constraints. This means that if an `Element*` is deleted, you need to delete any `Editorials` that it's morphed to manually, whereas in a normal `Many to Many` relationship you could set a foreign key constraint and the RDBMS does this for you.

**note 2:** First of all I would try to see if those Element tables can be unified into a single table. If they can your work would get a lot easier. But if you have to use many Element tables, I think both ways are fine. Each has an advantage and a disadvantage.It's many relationship tables or polymorphic relationships which you have to handle database consistency yourself, And in either way you can't do `$editorial->elements()` with a relationship.

Comment: So you think the only solution is to have multiple relationships for each element type in the editorials model? Ideally i just want one "elements" relationship which brings them all in.

Comment: @VinceLowe Edited my answer. Read note 2

Comment: @FarzinFarzanehnia Hey, would you mind checking out my answer? Just curious to see your thoughts.

Comment: @RichardVanbergen There are some issues I see that I'll try to point out. First issue is that your elements table is basically a pivot table for a Many to Many polymorphic relationship. So you basically are using the idea of such relationship. The second problem is that calling elements() on editorial wouldn't return a collection of Element*'s, for that you need to use nested relationships. So you have to say Editorial::with('elements.text', 'elements.image', ...). which again does simplify the job at hand at all.

Comment: @RichardVanbergen sorry for answering here. SO doesn't let me comment elsewhere right now.